# SSH to server and execute and print commands

Tags: shell-script, shell, ssh

I have a server AA and from the shell script have to connect to server BB using ssh. On server BB, I want to check if the given folder is empty or not, if not empty it should remove all files & directories.

But o/p and print commands should be printed on server AA.

Tried with below script but after ssh, the commands are executing on the current server.  After SSH, it was displaying nothing. Please help me.

```
IFS='=' read -r -a param1 <<< "$1"
user=${param1[1]}
IFS='=' read -r -a param2 <<< "$2"
server=${param2[1]}
IFS='=' read -r -a param3 <<< "$3"
folder_path=${param3[1]}
ssh $user@$server <<EOF
echo $(hostname)
if [ -d $folder_path ] 
 then
{
 cd $folder_path 
 rm -rf $folder_path/* 
}
echo "Files under $folder_path has been deleted successfully 
exit 0
else
echo "No such file/folder"
exit 1
fi
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your script, and it's working fine if you just remove the line "cd $folder_path", and it needs key-value pairs in exact order:

```
./script user=username server=192.168.3.14 folder=fodername
```

But the single command can replace all script:

```
ssh user@server rm -rf foldername/\*
```

Comment: This script is getting executed but not on the tagert server BB , but on server AA. 
Tried with the  script you suggested, nothing happened on server AA or BB (we have the same path is both the servers)

Comment: It worked, seems to be issue with ssh.. Thanks for the help